# What is Solr query result cache working mechanism?

Tags: solr

I am trying to understand whether Solr Query Result Cache would store 'full query's result' or 'main query result'.

https://teaspoon-consulting.com/articles/solr-cache-tuning.html

q=country:US&fq=state:CA. Assume main query matched 100 docs. Filter works on 100 docs and result is 10 docs. Would the query cache hold the 100 doc IDs or just 10 doc IDs. Meaning, full result or just the main query result ? Becoz the above blog read that the query cache would hold 100 docs. But the query result cache code show that the key to the result set cache includes filter as well. Wish to get a confirmation.

Can I have any expertise confirm this behavior? Having to run a solr from source and debug in intellij is a pain.

Answer (score -1):

On a quick glance, that article is confusing. Apologies if a more careful reading would clear things up.

queryResultCache does *not* store the entire result set, it stores queryResultWindowSize (specified in solrconfig.xml). So if your query matches 1,000,000 docs and queryResultWindowSize is 50, only 50 doc Ids are stored in this cache for this query (10 in your example). Think of this is a cache intended to store a few pages worth of IDs so when a user hits "next", the query doesn't have to be re-executed.

In my example, the query won't have to be re-executed until &start + &rows exceeds 50. Then 50 more docs a new entry in the cache starting at &start. The docs stored respect everything about the query. Sort order, scores, fq's applied start, etc. It'd be impractical to store, say, 1M doc Ids in this cache, especially when you consider that the *exact* same query is rare and that you'd then have to keep a sorted list 1,000,000 (in my example), aka the "deep paging" problem.

The article also talks about the filterCache, which *does* hold the entire result set. However, it is simply a bitset bounded by maxDocs/8 with a bit on for each document that satisfies the fq clause. In my example, this bitset will have 1,000,000 bits set and, if there are 8M docs in the index, would be roughly a megabyte (i.e. maxDoc=8,000,000). This is a much different problem than queryResultCache since there's no sorting involved and Lucene has to score each doc. Flipping a bit whenever the score is non-zero adds trivially to the execution time.